# How to find unused resource dictionaries

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a big solution with many projects. Most of controls connect several resource dictionaries using MergedDictionaries. Is there any way to find out which resource dictionaries are not used any more and could be easily removed from merged dictionaries.

I'm aware about SharedResourceDictionary approach, but I can't use that right away. So, that's not an option for now.

Comment: is grepping through the whole project not an option?

Comment: Prefix all your resource names with "tmp", then try to compile/run to see what's missing. Correct missing resources by removing "tmp", and everythink is working, search for remaining "tmp"

Comment: Renaming each resource and then verifying that app starts and works normally is not acceptable. Too many styles, dictionaries, controls and app startup takes a lot of time. I thought there is some tool which could help to solve the problem.